# Having issues with the from

Tags: php, mysql, socialengine

I have an issue with the form. For some reason it does not populate the table I named *About*

Table info (About):
user_id,
aboutme_id,
about,

Table info (Users):
user_id,
...,
...,
...,
etc.

**Form:**

```
 $this->addElement('textarea', 'description', array(
      'label' => 'Body Content',
      'required' => true,
      'allowEmpty' => false,
    ));
```

Verification

```
public function onProcess()
  {
    // In this case, the step was placed before the account step.
    // Register a hook to this method for onUserCreateAfter
    if( !$this->_registry->user ) {
      // Register temporary hook
      Engine_Hooks_Dispatcher::getInstance()->addEvent('onUserCreateAfter', array(
        'callback' => array($this, 'onProcess'),
      ));
      return;
    }
    $user = $this->_registry->user;

    $data = $this->getSession()->data;
    $form = $this->getForm();
    if( !$this->_skip && !$this->getSession()->skip ) {
      if( $form->isValid($data) ) {
        $values = $form->getValues();
        $table = Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('about', 'user');
            $rName = $table->info('name');
                $userTable = Engine_Api::_()->getDbtable('users', 'user')->info('name');
                $select = $select
        ->setIntegrityCheck(false)
        ->from($userTable)
        ->joinLeft($userTable, "$userTable.user_id = $rName.user_id")
        ->where($userTable, "$userTable.user_id = $rName.user_id");

      }
    }
  }
```

Any idea what is going on with this picture?

Answer (score 0):

Try to test database table operations in a sample empty action of some controller using `echo "<pre>"; print_r(); echo "</pre>"; die();` to debug results. You can also use `$select->__toString()` to get raw sql of constructed query.

Also take a look at /temporary/log/main.log for some notices/errors.